# Give a non-zero $R$-module $M$ such that $M \oplus M \cong M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, direct-sum

For some reason this hasn't been asked before and I can't seem to find an example. Here $R$ is a commutative ring.

Find a non-zero $R$-module $M$ such that $M \oplus M \cong M$

Comment: How about $R^{\infty} \cong R^{\infty} \oplus R^{\infty}$ where $R^{\infty} = \oplus_{\mathbb{Z}} R$?

Comment: I thought of that too but was unable to find an isomorphism. But I think I've found one now. Take the map $M \oplus M \to M$ that sends everything in the first copy of $M$ to the 'even' places in $M$ and the second copy to the 'odd' places.

Comment: @AnneBauval less so than Alvin's comment.

Comment: The construction of an isomorphism: $f:( \oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}R)\oplus (\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}R)\to \oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}R$ is easy. A construction is:
\begin{equation*}
(r_1,r_2,\cdots)\oplus(s_1,s_2,\cdots)\mapsto (r_1,s_1,r_2,s_2,\cdots).
\end{equation*}
That is just like constructing a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}_+\times\{0,1\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: @Asigan Yes, that is what I said, isn't it?

Comment: @soggycornflakes Ah, yes. Sorry maybe I did not see your comment while replying.